# Where in the registry can I find the OS Name for Windows 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-registry

I need to be able to read the registry and find the Edition of Windows 2003. I can find the edition of Windows 2008 and Windows 2008 R2 by looking into:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\@ProductName

and I see something like:

"Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard" or "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise"

However, when I look at this value in Windows 2003, I only see:

"Microsoft Windows Server 2003 R2" with no Edition (e.g. Standard or Enterprise) information.

I have looked everywhere in the registry for something to help me to find the edition information, but I cannot find it. I can see it in System Information, but nowhere in the registry?!

I need this information, as I need to work out which one I am working with for an inventory.

Comment: Are you creating a program to do this? It can be determined programatically if that's an option.

Comment: It can be determined from a combination of other values but is not stored in the registry in human readable form.

Comment: I am using an inventory system that can look into the registry and read anything it wants. That is how I am getting the Windows 2008/XP/2008 R2 information. Windows 2003 is the exception. I donj't care if it is human-readable, I just need to detect the value and my system will then understand that and turn it into human-readable... So, wher is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a real hack, but I think that I have found the ANSWER!

If you go to HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\@ProductId, the first 5 numbers before the dash are the edition number. I can identify it from there.

Can anyone confirm or denie this?

Answer (score 2):

A more portable and probably reliable option would be to check these values via WMI - you'd be interested in the Win32_OperatingSystem class.

[Technet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394596(v=vs.85).aspx) has a brief primer with vbscript code on this class.

Comment: I am doing it programmatically, but I cannot use WMI. :-( I just need to know the registry value and if it is set, then it responds back with a yes or a no.

Comment: This does not work on Windows 2003, either, according to the page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @QuietLeni sure it does, that link is Win32_ComputerSystem NOT Win32_OperatingSystem - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have to do it via the registry, but the command "winver" in the run box returns that information.